# Intermittent kitchen outlet power

Tags: electrical, receptacle, kitchens

I have several outlets in my kitchen.  My kitchen was completely remodeled 10 years ago. When I plug in an appliance, eg a mixer or a food processor for example, everything is fine until I turn the appliance off. When I need to turn it on again, it very often does not work and I am left in the middle of a recipe with no power.  The appliance has not overheated. If the appliance is small. I will unplug it and try another outlet in the kitchen and still nothing.  The green light on the outlet is on so the reset button has not tripped and the circuit breakers are fine.  Why would all the outlets on the room not work at the same time? I rarely use 2 appliances at once and the outlet usually works again a couple of hours later. But you can imagine this is a huge problem in the middle of cooking. I would love your help. Thank you.

Comment: One of two problems.  One is you have a loose connection or two your GFCI outlet is going wonky.  Loose connection just turn off the breaker, check for no power and tighten the connections.  Wonky GFCI will need to replace.  Ten years I would go with wonky.

Comment: Do the circuit breakers that power your kitchen outlets have separate handles, or do they have two handles with a plastic or metal bridge connecting them? Is there just one GFCI outlet (the one with the green light)? If you push the trip button intentionally, do all outlets lose power or do only some of them?

Answer (score 2):

I’m curious if the outlet you’re plugging into has had the wires backstabbed into the outlet vs having them looped around. I’d start by confirming that the machine you are using works in a different room. However if the problem happens with multiple different appliances I’d jiggle the hell out of the cord and plug it in and out repeatedly to see if you can get it to work. If it does I’d say loose connection. If not then like Crip659 had said it’s quite possible that the GFCI is causing your problems in some form or another. Truthfully in a kitchen nearly all or at least the outlets anywhere near the sink should come after the GFCI.